# Gradle project running jUnit 5 tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit, junit5

I am trying both Gradle and jUnit5 right now. Everything works fine except that I cannot run a specific jUnit test. The "Run 'SampleTest'" option does not appear when I right-click a test class.

I have the latest version of IntelliJ (2016.1.3) Ultimate. Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'

version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

jar {
    baseName = 'test-project'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.0.0-M1'
}
```

The project structure is the standard one (like in Maven). And here is an example of a test:

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SampleTest {
  @Test public void sampleTest() {
    int test = 1;
    Assertions.assertTrue(test == 1);
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

It seems that Gradle is not picking up my test either. When I go to `build/reports/tests/index.html`, it indicates 0 test.

**FINAL EDIT:**

Following @dunny's answer, here is what I did to make everything work. I modified my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

jar {
    baseName = 'test-project'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.0.0-M1'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.0.0-M1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testRuntime group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.0.0-M1'
}

test {
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ, I then opened the Gradle window, and clicked on the "refresh all gradle projects" button, to refresh the libraries.

Then in my test class, I added `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` on top of the class declaration.

And when I do a `gradle build`, the results are available here: `build\test-results\junit-platform\TEST-junit-jupiter.xml`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IntelliJ 2016.1.3 doesn't have support for JUnit 5 tests. You can however add the annotation `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`, which would execute your test in a JUnit 4 compatibility mode (you can still use all JUnit 5 features). See http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner for more information.

For Gradle you need to include the Gradle JUnit 5 plugin to enable support:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // The following is only necessary if you want to use SNAPSHOT releases.
        // maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
```

See http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build

Comment: IntelliJ 2016.2 now has support for JUnit5. Just use the build.gradle file edited into the question by @Jean-FrançoisBeauchef as the solution.

Answer (score 13):

The latest Idea 2016.2 supports JUnit 5 framework now. You can directly run JUnit5 test without junit-gradle-plugin any more. Please see [WHAT'S NEW IN INTELLIJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-2-java). After you upgraded your Idea to this new version, You can create a gradle project and do following steps to test how to run JUnit 5 test.

- build.gradle

  ```
  apply plugin: 'java'

  compileTestJava {
      sourceCompatibility = 1.8
      targetCompatibility = 1.8
  }

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
      testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M1")
      testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0-M1")
      //NOTE: if you replaced above testRuntime dependency with following
      //testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M1")
      //this test would fail.
  }
  ```
- Create a class FirstJUnit5Test in your test source folder

  ```
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

  public class FirstJUnit5Test {
      @Test
      void myFirstTest() {
          assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
      }
  }
  ```
- Right click on this test class in the left project pane, and then select "Run 'FirstJUnit5Test'. You will see the result as following:
  [image]
- For more information, you can checkout [this project from github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.0.0-M1/junit5-gradle-consumer).

**UPDATE**

For IDEA 2016.3.3 and higher, the `dependencies` configuration can be simplified to:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M3")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [run your tests with the JUnit 4 runner](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner), since IntelliJ 2016.1.3 doesn't have JUnit 5 test runner.

If you are starting from the example `pom.xml` linked in the documentation, https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.0.0-M1/junit5-maven-consumer/pom.xml, then do the following two things.

Add one more dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

then **make your test class public** and annotate it with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`.

Your IDE will now recognize the class as a test and will provide integration.

Comment: Thanks, but everything was already said by dunni, except for the pom.xml part, but I am not using Maven. I am using Gradle. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jean and making the test class public. JUnit5 can work without it, JUnit4 doesn't. Switching the dependency declaration into Gradle syntax should be trivial for a Gradle user.

Comment: But my test class is public?

Comment: It wouldn't have to be if you were using Junit5 with a Junit5 runner...

Comment: Ah ok, I see. But I was trying to understand what was wrong with what I was doing. But thanks anyway.